# How do I schedule a PHP function every 2 month?

Tags: cron

I need, every 2 months, to execute some rule component programmatically, but I don't know how to do this.

If I use `hook_cron()`, I don't know how to check 2 months are passed from the last time it was executed.

I can check *'the 10th day of the month' + 'month number is even'*.

If cron tasks run twice a day, I cannot send 2 identical emails to users.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You'll need to write some logic to check the current date/time, against a value you store the last time your cron job ran. That logic isn't Drupal-specific (just basic PHP) so we can't help you with it here; but you'll probably want to use variable_get/variable_set to store/retrieve your timestamp

Comment: Or alternatively run a system cron job (eg 0 0 1 */2 *) possibly calling a php cli script (provided you have shell access).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easly do this without having access to crontab/shell, by using following code in your cron_hook:

```
// check if current day is 10th and month is an even number
if (date('d')==10 && date('m') % 2 == 0) {
    // get todays-date (format: yyyymmdd)
    $today = date('Ymd');
    // get info about last run
    $last_run = variable_get('my_last_run', 0);
    // check last run was not today
    if ($last_run!=$today) {
        // set last run to today
        variable_set('my_last_run', $today);

        /* Place your code here */

    }
}
```

For more info on the modulo-operator (the % ) check:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

Comment: Using this method is useful install Elysia Cron

Comment: Why install a module if you can achieve this with a simple php function?

Comment: This is not work !!!

Comment: @shyghar , do u have process that execute every second and check your condtions?!!!!!!!!!!! , This is not correct way ,if you think it work in php , I tell you are mistakes, because php not run any function any second to check your condition available,if you put it in default drupal raw, it run when only cron run .by the way this is completely mistake method !!!!

Comment: Nope.. I inserted this code in a hook_cron() so this code will be executed only with mt drupal cron [once a day]..

Answer (score 1):

Rules has a submodule called rules_scheduler made for that purpose.

Answer (score -2):

The best way is use [crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) ,create a php file as example `mycorn.php` trigger your rule in it and  create a crontab to run your php file every 2 month.
Just one note, please set permission  only owner can execute it.

Below  links help you , how to set cron.

http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/